# Hiding nodes in the model tree of EMF Compare

Tags: eclipse, emf-compare

I would like to hide some tree nodes in the match results of EMF Compare, since they are just containers with no meaning to our users.

I have tried two approaches, but both result in some unwanted side-effects.

1. Using a more narrow scope
          Details: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/781759/
   This
       results in the separate diffs being available, but without the
       enclosing tree structure of the model.

   Using a post processor to remove some container objects from the tree of matches.
           Details: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/781794/
           This is more of a success in that the resulting tree structure is exactly what I'm after. This however breaks navigation in the bottom pane.

I'd be really happy if someone could have a look and see what my attempts are missing.

Thanks,

Mattias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a reply in the Eclipse forum. An EMF Compare core dev let me know that this is not possible without breaking behaviour as I described.

So for the rest of you trying: no dice.